# I am following the Wormhole SDK to bridge from Fantom to Terra. and while I try to get signedVAA I got < ReferenceError: self is not defined>

Tags: blockchain, nodejs

```
const WORMHOLE_RPC_HOSTS = 'https://wormhole-v2-testnet-api.certus.one'
```

```
const { signedVAA } = await getSignedVAA(
        WORMHOLE_RPC_HOSTS,
        CHAIN_ID_TERRA,
        emitterAddress,
        sequence,
    )
```

the error is

```
(node:10434) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: self is not defined
    at new e (/Users/beki/cryptup/kryptup-blockchain/node_modules/@improbable-eng/grpc-web/dist/grpc-web-client.js:1:16017)
    at /Users/beki/cryptup/kryptup-blockchain/node_modules/@improbable-eng/grpc-web/dist/grpc-web-client.js:1:15931
    at /Users/beki/cryptup/kryptup-blockchain/node_modules/@improbable-eng/grpc-web/dist/grpc-web-client.js:1:15942
    at o (/Users/beki/cryptup/kryptup-blockchain/node_modules/@improbable-eng/grpc-web/dist/grpc-web-client.js:1:15312)
    at Object.t.makeDefaultTransport (/Users/beki/cryptup/kryptup-blockchain/node_modules/@improbable-eng/grpc-web/dist/grpc-web-client.js:1:15405)
```

Answer (score 0):

fetch the signedVAA directly by using public rpc.

```
 fetch(`https://wormhole-v2-mainnet api.certus.one/v1/signed_vaa/3/${emitterAddress}/${sequence}`
    );
```